# Connect my router to the internet via another router?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, lan, wan

What I want to do: Connect to the internet through my wifi router, via some other router that the room I rent provides.

What I have: 1 ethernet cable that comes into my apartment.

If I plug the ethernet cable into my computer it will work fine. I'm guess DHCP gives me my ip address and viola, 192.168.1.1 is my gateway (and I can see some router admin page that I have no control over or ownership of). Howver, if I plug this same ethernet cable into my otherwise working wifi router (have done this kind of setup before in the past) it fails to connect to the internet. I am using dd-wrt and it is set to Gateway mode and to use DHCP as the connection type.

I noticed that when my router is plugged in, it does not have a gateway ip set (perhaps because it is the gateway) for what it's worth.

edit: This is in Thailand. I suspect the LAN cable goes directly to the WAN and not through a modem. Not sure.

Comment: If the initial router doesn't allow you to bridge, you won't be able to do this. Have you set up your router as an "extender"?

Comment: I have tried setting my router connect type to both gateway and router... no luck. I am trying to get my wifi router working over the single LAN cable provided... However one thought has occured to me... would it be possible to plug the provided LAN ethernet cable into the regular LAN slot and then point my windows network connection's "gateway IP" to the LAN IP of the router?

Comment: depends on the architecture of the network that exists. Worth a try.

Comment: Does your WiFi router also use 192.168.1.0/24 as its internal network? There's no reason you can't chain NATs like that, but you have to keep the various internal network spaces from stepping on each others' toes.

Comment: @Bandami I think so, what should I change it to since the parent most router is using 192.168.1.0/24 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens often that people enable MAC filtering, in a misguided attempt at controlling access. The fact that your router does not receive an IP address seems to suggest as much.

This is a misguided attempt because it is easily thwarted,as I now show you. Your pc is obviously allowed to connect via ethernet, so first thing determine the MAC address of your ethernet card (you can easily Google that).

Then open the GUI of your DD-WRT router, Setup -> Mac Address Clone -> Enable, and fill in the relevant info. Save configuration, reboot, you **might** be good to go.

Edit:

Another possible cause of malfunction is if both routers are using a subnet 192.168.1.0/24, which would make it impossible, for router 2, to understand whether any given address lies on the LAN or on the WAN side. Try changing the subnet on the LAN side of router 2.

Comment: My router receives an IP address. It was 192.168.1.14  but in its configuration, the gateway was not set which I found odd. I'm wondering, how would it know when to send traffic upwards? I did try enable mac address cloning of my laptop (Which connects fine) and no dice.

Comment: @Zombies I have edited my answer to gsuggest a different solution to your problem.

Comment: Edit, or the second answer is what fixed the issue. I changed my routers IP address to 192.168.2.55  ..the 55 just being arbitrary, I'm sure it would also work as 192.168.2.55 and I set the connection type BACK to gateway (default) mode.